# Using past perfect tense after past tense

Tags: past-tense, past-perfect

Which sentence is more correct?

1. He helped an old woman. Then, everyone had known that he was a good man.
2. He helped an old woman. Now, everyone has known that he is a good man.

I know that past perfect is used to describe an event that happened before the one used with past simple. Thus, I'm not sure if I can use it as in the example (1) in which the sentence with past perfect happened after the one with past simple.

Thank you very much in advance for every answer.

Comment: a). He helped an old woman. Then everyone realised that he was a good man.          b.) He helped an old woman. Now everyone has realised that he is a good man.

Answer (score 0):

Your first sentence uses the pluperfect/past perfect tense, ie., "had known".

> He helped an old woman. Then, everyone had known that he was a good
>   man.
>   ____________________________^^^^^^^^^ (past perfect tense/pluperfect)

And your second sentence uses the present perfect, ie., "has known".

> He helped an old woman. Now, everyone has known that he is a good
>   man.
>   ____________________________^^^^^^^^ (present perfect tense)

In the second sentence I think the simple present would be for fitting:

> "He helped an old woman. Now, everyone knows that he is a good
>   man.
>   _____________________________        ^^^^ (simple present tense)

I would use either your first sentence, or my simple present tense example, but not your second one, which sounds really strange. However, I can't at the moment explain why exactly in relation to the other tenses.

Comment: "Knows" is *not* simple past. It is 3rd person present. The past form is "knew".

Comment: @RoaringFish Well picked up, and thanks for the correction. I know you're trawling my answers looking for an excuse to downvote. That's two you've made within minutes of my last response to you in that other thread. You're certainly rancorous towards me to take the time to check my answers in such a interested way. I could do the very same thing to you, if I were that type of guy.

Comment: I downvoted this one because it was wrong (and still is... "or my simple past tense example", but I will correct it for you). Other than that you have a bit of a persecution thing going on....

Comment: @RoaringFish Yeah, it's just coincidence that my answers are being challenged and downvoted directly after you stopped engaging me in our other discussion. The only persecution thing I got going on is that you're persecuting me.

Comment: The last time I checked, there were 9,170,126 users on this site, so yes - you are being a but paranoid imagining that every downvote you get must be me....   Yes, I am browsing to see if you have given any other incorrect answers. At least until I get bored of it.

Comment: @RoaringFish So after telling me I got a persecution thing going, you then admit that you're browsing my answers to check if they are incorrect. Yeah, that sounds like totally normal behaviour. Single out a user, go through his answers and check if they are incorrect. You're a funny piece of work.

Comment: Actually, I am a long-term, high-rep user checking on a low-rep user who appears to give a lot of questionable advice. That is not being "a funny piece of work". That is looking out for the site's standards.

Comment: @RoaringFish  Questionable advice is your own value judgment not borne out by my vote count. As far as I see it you've had more downvotes than I have so maybe you're the one offering "questionable advice". I've only been using this site on and off since March and have the rep I have. So the fact that you're singling me out on account of your suspicion that I'm offering questionable advice seems suspect.